# Clicking NSSegmentedControl in unselected NSTableView row always produces -1 as output

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, osx-elcapitan, nssegmentedcontrol

Sample project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_fZh7kpxha7Y0JfU0xYMGpiMVE/view?usp=sharing

If you select a table row then select segments in the NSSegmentedCell, you can see in the log that the correct output is being produced. However, if you switch between NSSegmentedCells in different rows, the NSSegmentedCell constantly produces -1 as output (no segment selected).

I discovered this when trying to fix a bug that arose in one of my apps in El Capitan so I'm not sure if it's a bug with the operating system or if I'm doing something incorrectly.

Thanks in advance!